# Sphinx documentation: how to disable default argument expansion?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have some functions like

```
f(x, propagation_speed=scipy.constants.c)
```

I run `sphinx-apidoc` to generate documentation on them and them `make html` to get final HTML data.

Alas, Sphinx expands the constants and gives me something like

```
f(x, propagation_speed=299792458.0)
```

Cannot I somehow disable the default values expansion in docstrings? Could I add something to `conf.py`?

Comment: I don't believe it's expanding the values, it's retrieving the [function's signature](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#signatures) python creates at function definition time [as you can do yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677185/how-can-i-read-a-functions-signature). This is all Sphinx can see to get the data for the function signature shown on the documentation.

Comment: This also has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287477/can-i-suppress-variable-expansion-in-sphinx-documentation) but no one figured out an acceptable answer to it then, so I'm sure they'll be interested in any answers you find.

Answer (score 0):

A (dirty) fix. In your `conf.py` file add:

```py
import re

def remove_default_value(app, what, name, obj, options, signature, return_annotation):
    if signature:
        search = re.findall(r"(\w*)=", signature)
        if search:
            signature = "({})".format(", ".join([s for s in search]))

    return (signature, return_annotation)

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-process-signature", remove_default_value)
```